# My mouse is displaying even though I made it invisible?

Tags: game-engine, camera, mouse

So I am making a game and have been on this one for about a week now. And just now am dealing with this issue. I know how to make a mouse appear and disappear as I wish it to on the game engine. However, just recently, I press P to play the game to test it out and the mouse is on the screen.

Even if I look through cameras or not, it is showing. So here is what I already did to try to fix this issue. I made sure no scenes were overlaying with the mouse visible. I made all cameras that will be used have and invisible mouse. I even googled as much as I could possibly find and only found that on the right panel, under render it can have the mouse active... And it wasn't.

Also, when I am playing the game, not only is the mouse in the middle of the screen but as I rotate the camera around with the mouse. The Screen mouse gets huge. Which can cause a huge issue if you are playing a game.

Answer (score 1):

So I did a little more digging on this. And realized that is was an issue that should have never been an issue in the first place. A few days ago I made a pause scene and had an **invisible mouse actuator** connected to an **always Sensor** I had to delete those two connectors for the mouse to not show up. This seems to be a glitch so if anyone comes across an issue similar to this. I would check your mouse actuators you made a while ago....